# downloading 2 subset files in R - Shiny

Tags: r, download, shiny, subset

I'm creating an app for our partners that lets them upload their own csv contact list, randomly sample a group from that file, and then let them download separate csvs for each the sampled group and the remaining group.  Everything appears to run fine and I get no error codes but when I attempt to download the parsed data frames, I am only given the original list in its entirety.  I am assuming this has something to do with the file argument possibly referencing the file path created during the file upload but I do not know enough to be able to verify and/or modify this process for testing.

Code isn't very long and figured it might be best for you to be able to replicate the app so below is the whole shebang (more or less)

ui.r

```
library(shiny)
source('server.R')

shinyUI(fluidPage(

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("file1", "Choose a CSV file:",
                accept = c('text/csv',
                           'text/comma-separated-values',
                           'text/plain',
                           '.csv')),
      tags$hr(),
      checkboxInput("header", "This file has headers.", FALSE),
      radioButtons("sep", "What kind of separators does this file use?",
                   c(Comma = ',',
                     Semicolon = ';',
                     Tab = '\t'),
                   ','),
      radioButtons('quote', 
                   "Are any of the values in this table surrounded by
                   quotation marks?  i.e. 'Adam Smith'",
                   c("None" = '',
                     "Double Quotes (\" \")" = '"',
                     "Single Quotes (\' \')" = "'"),
                   ''), 

      h3("Sample creation"),

      numericInput("sampleSize", 
                   "How many entries would you like for your sample?",
                   value = 0,
                   step = 1),
      conditionalPanel(
        condition = "output.recommend !== NULL",
        textOutput("recommend"))
    ), 

    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Original Table", tableOutput("contents")),
        tabPanel("Sample Group", downloadButton("sampleDL", 
                 "Download this table"), 
                 tableOutput("sampled")),
        tabPanel("Remaining Group", downloadButton("remainDL", 
                 "Download this table"),
                 tableOutput("remains"))
        )
      )
    )
  )
)
```

server.R

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  dataset <- reactive({
    if(is.null(input$file1)){
      return(NULL)
    } else {
      info <- input$file1
      data <- read.csv(info$datapath, header=input$header, 
              sep=input$sep, quote=input$quote)
      entID <- 1:(as.integer(nrow(data)))
      dataset <- data.frame(entID, data)
      cbind(dataset)
      dataset[sample(1:nrow(dataset)),]
      return(dataset)
    }
  })

  sugSample <- function(){
    dataset <- dataset()
    if(is.null(dataset)){
      return(NULL)
    } else {
      size <- nrow(dataset)
      if(size <= 3){
        return(NULL)
      }else {
        sSize <- size * 0.167
        return(as.integer(sSize))
      }
    }
  }

  output$recommend <- renderText({
    sugSample <- sugSample() 
    if(is.null(sugSample)){
      return("There is nothing from which to sample at this time.")
    } else {
      return(paste0("Based on the size of your dataset, 
                    I recommend choosing at least ", 
                    sugSample, 
                    " entries for your sample size."))
    }
 })

  sampleGroup <- reactive({
  sSize <- input$sampleSize  
  if(sSize == 0){
      x <- "there is nothing to display"
      y <- "there is nothing to display"
      z <- "there is nothing to display"
      blank <- data.frame(x,y,z)
      return(blank)
    } else {
      dataset <- dataset()
      oSize <- as.integer(nrow(dataset))
      sampleGroup <- dataset[(sample(1:oSize, sSize, replace = FALSE)),]
      return(data.frame(sampleGroup))
    }
  })

  remainGroup <- reactive({
    if(input$sampleSize == 0){
      x <- "there is nothing to display"
      y <- "there is nothing to display"
      z <- "there is nothing to display"
      blank <- data.frame(x,y,z)
      return(blank)
    } else {
    dataset <- dataset()
    sampleGroup <- sampleGroup()
    remainGroup <- dataset[which(!(dataset$entID %in% sampleGroup$entID)),]
    return(data.frame(remainGroup))
    }
  })

  output$contents <- renderTable({
    dataset <- dataset()
    if(is.null(dataset)){
      x <- 'there is nothing to display'
      y <- 'there is nothing to display'
      z <- 'there is nothing to display'
      blank <- data.frame(x,y,z)
      return(blank)
    } else {
      return(dataset)
    }
    })

  output$sampled <- renderTable({
    sampleGroup <- sampleGroup()
    return(sampleGroup)
  })

  output$sampleDL <- downloadHandler(
    filename = 'sampleGroup.csv',
    content = function(file){
      write.csv(sampleGroup(), file)
    })

  output$remains <- renderTable({
    remainGroup <- remainGroup()
    return(remainGroup)
  })

  output$remainDL <- downloadHandler(
    filename = 'remainingGroup.csv',
    content = function(file){
      write.csv(remainGroup(), file)
    })
})
```

THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

downloadHandler() does not function as expected from within RStudio as the processes require Flash, which RStudio does not have.  Launched app in *browser* and download files were as expected.